# protractor with javascript vs typescript which one is mostly useful

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, protractor, ui-automation

I want to learn and implement automation framework using protractor for an angular web application.

I have come across with

- protractor with JS framework
- protractor with typescript and cucumber framework

Which one is most robust, easy, user friendly and used across industry.

Please advise.

Comment: Not sure if the question fits StackOverflow format, but here is a quite relevant SQA discussion: [Switching from JavaScript to TypeScript for Protractor e2e tests](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/28105/5574).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they're exactly the same.
I find it easier with JavaScript because it's easier to check the StrackTrace log.

With TypeScript, everything gets recompiled again, everything gets transpiled and it's a bit difficult to follow and debug your own code. If you're a newbie, I'd suggest that you start with Protractor and JavaScript.

Here. I've created a starters repository for protractor. Let me know if you have any questions. I will update this, and transform it in a tutorial soon.

```
npm install -g protractor
npm install -g grunt
npm install
```

https://github.com/theITed/protractor-with-grunt

Answer (score 0):

**You can go with typescript because of the following reasons**

1. Typescript is  easy as compare with js
2. if you know any native language like c# java .. it is similar
3. you can easily customized your framework using typescript.
4. easily create your own complex utilities method...
5. many library available to  read excel file in typescript

example how to make custom method in typescript

export class WebElementLocator {

```
static async  getOptions() {
    return element.all(by.tagName('option'));
}
static async getDropDownByID(id, text) {

    await element(by.id(id)).all(by.cssContainingText('option', text)).click();
}
static async selectByValue(value) {
    return await element.all(by.css('option[value="' + value + '"]')).click();
}

static async getSelectedOptions() {

    return element.all(by.css('option[selected="selected"]'));
}

static async selectByPartialText(text) {
    return await element.all(by.cssContainingText('option', text)).click();
}

static async selectByText(text) {
    return await element.all(by.xpath('option[.="' + text + '"]')).click();
}

static async ngclick(method:string)
{
  await  element(by.css('[ng-click="'+method+'"]')).click();
}
```

}

now you can call any above method like as

WebElementLocator.getOptions();